# Is there a way to merge Dynamic XFA documents using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Is there a way to merge Dynamic XFA documents generated by Adobe LiveCycle using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do so.